# Is it possible to use Magic Launcher with Minecraft 1.6.1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I tried [Minecraft 1.6.1](http://mcupdate.tumblr.com/post/54337149404/minecraft-1-6-1) a couple of days ago and noticed that the Launcher and the directory layout changed.

I wonder if there is any information available if Magic Launcher supports 1.6.1 and if I can just use it as before, switching back and forth between 1.5.x and 1.6.x versions?

I also read on some forums that I could use the new launcher to do everything that Magic Launcher can do. Is that true? And if yes, is there a tutorial available somewhere?

Comment: Did you even try? It works right out of the box. Please try to solve your own problems before posting.

Comment: Snailer sure, I tried. But setting the environment as @shanodin described in his very helpful answer is not that obvious. Also It did not work for me when I tried it, maybe because I didn't downloaded the correct version with the launcher or because something else I did before. Anyway, I think there are enough people with this question coming to arcade in the future to leave this here as a reference.

Comment: @cringe ~her~ answer, thank you :) also if my answer was helpful, please mark as accepted ^_^

Comment: Ups, sorry for that @shanodin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you can use Magic Launcher with Minecraft 1.6

[image: Magic Launcher & MC 1.6]

Choose 1.6.x from the 'Environment' dropdown.

As for the new Minecraft launcher, I still find Magic Launcher to be more functional.

Comment: What do i do because when i put 1.6.1 in them then find the file of the latest minecraft it says invalid. Here is what it is like. Minecraft.jar: Invalid Minecraft.exe.
Please help

Answer (score -3):

Well the new launcher although it does offer multiple jars and minecraft instances it's not quite the same as magic launcher. On the subject of using magic launcher with 1.6.x. he explains the method to get 1.6.x. If you really need to update what you can do is update through the official launcher then move your files over into magic launcher manually.